# Convert for loop into list comprehension with assignment?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert a for loop with an assignment into a list comprehension.

More precisely I am trying to only replace one element from a list with three indexes.

Can it be done?

```
for i in range(len(data)):
data[i][0] =  data[i][0].replace('+00:00','Z').replace(' ','T')
```

Best

Comment: List Comprehension is used to make a new `list`. So it is not recommended to use here when you are trying to replace an element

Comment: Some things are best left as a regular loop, but you can simplify it as `for x in data: x[0] = x[0].replace(...)`

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the quick answer guys!

Comment: Even if you want a `List comprehension`, you could try doing it.

Comment: List comprehensions are for comprehending a list, you're not trying to do that, you're trying to mutate data

Comment: Btw, I would recommend to look into the `datetime` module and its various ways of parsing and formatting dates and times. Generally, using tested utils is generally safer than using string manipulation for such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, *really* want to convert it to a list comprehension, you could try something like this, assuming the sub-lists have three elements, as you stated in the questions:

```
new_data = [[a.replace('+00:00','Z').replace(' ','T'), b, c] for (a, b, c) in data]
```

Note that this does not modify the existing list, but creates a new list, though. However, in this case I'd just stick with a regular `for` loop, which much better conveys what you are actually doing. Instead of iterating the indices, you could iterate the elements directly, though:

```
for x in data:
    x[0] =  x[0].replace('+00:00','Z').replace(' ','T')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be done, but that's not the best way to do that.
First you would create a big Jones Complexity for a foreign reader of your code.
Second you would exceed preferred amount of chars on a line, which is 80. Which again will bring complexity problems for a reader.
Third is that list comprehension made to return things from comprehensing of lists, here you change your original list. Not the best practice as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Although I don't recommend you use `list-comprehension` in this case, but if you really want to use it, here is a example.
- It can handle different length of `data`, if you need it.

#### code:

```
data = [["1 +00:00",""],["2 +00:00","",""],["3 +00:00"]]
print([[i[0].replace('+00:00','Z').replace(' ','T'),*i[1:]] for i in data])
```

#### result:

```
[['1TZ', ''], ['2TZ', '', ''], ['3TZ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is useful when making lists. So, it is not recommended here. But still, you can try this simple solution -

```
print([ele[0].replace('+00:00','Z').replace(' ','T') for ele in data])
```